# sqlcmd: no rows affected

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

When I run `exec dbo.subprogram` from SQL Server Management Studio, it executes and returns result as many rows affected.

But when I run from `cmd` 
`C:\Users\mssadmin>sqlcmd -S servername -d databasename -q "EXIT( exec dbo.subprogram)"`
it returns as 0 rows affected.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't affect any rows? Could it be possible that `dbo.subprogram` affects many rows when executed from SSMS and no rows when executed from sqlcmd? How about you post the actual code of this mysterious `dbo.subprogram`.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to return the number of rows, You need to create a text file A.SQL:

```
exec dbo.subprogram; 
:EXIT(select @@rowcount)
```

Because EXIT must be at the beginning of a line, so you can't use -Q. Then you call:

```
C:\> SQLCMD -S servername -d database -i A.SQL -o A.OUT
```

Then the returned values by EXIT will be in ERRORLEVEL... You can query with:

```
C:\> ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```